# Multiple Analog input for one channel ADC with Amplifier drivers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, adc, circuit-design

I have a concept of using a one channel ADC for three differents analog inputs sources.
My question is: should I worry if the the analog inputs have differents inputs impedance, one is very high internal impedance, the second is very low internal impedance and the third is zero internal impedance? ( OpAmp buffer between the ADC and the source analog  inputs)
If I only wanted to select one analog inputs at once, I thought of having a mosfest switch between the analog inputs and the OpAmp?
Below is the circuit with voltage controller switch used as Analog swich in LTspice.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right thing to do for any application is to make sure that you buffer the signal sufficiently before you feed it to the ADC.

How much buffering you need depends on the impedance of the source and the impedance of the ADC – which in turn will be given in the ADC's datasheet. Usually, we use ADC buffers (opamps in voltage follower configuration) to drive ADCs.

So, really, make all three inputs buffered. A quad-opamp IC costs literal cents, and the voltage follower configuration is really nothing but the input signal connected to the non-inverting input of the opamp, and the inverting input connected to the opamps output, and use the latter to drive the ADC. So, that's the cost of one connection plus the cost of one quad opamp to give every single input a reliable buffer. Do it!

Switching: You can switch buffered signals using an analog switch, but you shouldn't do that for high-impedance signals, typically. So, voltage buffer for each input, switch after that, ADC last.

Comment: so, for all kind signal impedance using a buffer (OpAmp) will solve the problem, whether it is low impedance or high impedance? (I post updated). can you explain to me why we need an analog switch instead of the digital switch?. I have only one information regarding the ADC, which is the sampling frequency of 1Mhz

Comment: re: your mosfet system is less accurate AND more work than a simple analog switch, ie. an IC meant exactly for the purpose of multiplexing inputs. and you should *NOT* be using different values for Rx, Ry, Rz. The whole point of the opamp buffers is to make them have the same impedance!

Comment: Of course, you'd typically terminate all inputs appropriately, especially for high-frequency signals. But yeah, my answer stands!

Comment: I have used different values for Rx, Ry, and Rz because I have already given the transfer function for each inputs that is injected accordingly to the input ADC, That is why I have calculated them so it fits those transfer function. I added another inverting opamp, because of the necessity to obtain all the transfer functions seen on the pic without the minus.

Comment: these resistors change nothing with respect to the transfer function if you model your opamps to be perfect. I think you're missing something here.

Comment: I have come up with a non-inverting summer but had to calculate it and i will upload it here